# Docker desktop for Mac: bind to tcp port

Tags: docker, tcp, docker-desktop, shinyproxy

I'm running ShinyProxy (https://www.shinyproxy.io/) locally on my mac, together with Docker Desktop for Mac.

ShinyProxy requires access to the Docker daemon via tcp, rather than just via unix socket.

Just to be clear, Docker desktop binds by default to `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`. I need it to bind to `http://127.0.0.1:2375`.

I can't seem to find a way to make Docker desktop bind to a tcp port. Has anyone solved this problem before?

Comment: That's an incredibly insecure configuration – at the very least it would allow any local process to get root access to the host with no controls – and I'd recommend filing a security bug against the project.  The ShinyProxy installation instructions seems to describe this setup pretty clearly, though.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, from what I could find, Docker Desktop for Mac does not bind to TCP by choice (I guess for obvious security reasons). And there is no way to change that.
So the workaround I found is the following:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:2375,range=127.0.0.1/32,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:/var/run/docker.sock
```

It basically reroutes the Unix socket to a tcp port (binding on localhost only).
This allowed me to access the Docker daemon via TCP.